# Dynamic allocation and pointers

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-allocation

```
int *ptr;      
ptr=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*2);       
ptr=100;    /*What will happen if I put an asterisk(*) indicating *ptr=100? */            
ptr++;        
printf("ptr=%d",*ptr);         
free(ptr);
```

So, I wanted the pointer to increment. I allocated a size of 4(2*2) for the pointer. But I couldn't understand how the pointer increments only by 2. And if I put an asterisk int the 3rd line,that is *ptr=100; It shows something else.

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169). Also don't print pointers with anything but `%p` and a cast to `void *`.

Comment: To be fair, and it may not be intentional, he is dereferencing that pointer in his `printf()` call, so `%d` is correct here and `%p` is not. The contents of the format string appear to indicate a desire to print the value of `ptr` and not the value of what it points to, but it's hard to know for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `int * ptr`, then `ptr++` increments the pointer by the size of a single `int`. If `int` is two bytes on your platform, that's why it increments by two.

`*ptr = 100` would store the value `100` at the `int` pointed to by `ptr`, i.e. the first of the two `int`s that you allocated with your `malloc()` call.

`ptr = 100` will attempt to assign the memory address `100` to `ptr`, which is almost certainly not what you want, as you would lose your reference to the memory you just `malloc()`ed, and what is at memory location `100` is probably not meaningful for you or accessible to you.

As it currently stands, if you were to do `*ptr = 100` and then `ptr++`, your `printf()` call would result in undefined behavior since you'd have incremented the pointer to point to uninitialized memory (i.e. the second of the two `int`s you allocated with your `malloc()` call), whose contents you then attempt to output.

`(*ptr)++` on the other hand would increment that `100` value to `101`, leave the value of `ptr` unchanged, your `printf()` call would be fine, and output `101`. The second of the two `int`s you allocate would still remain uninitialized, but that's no problem if you don't attempt to access it.

Also, don't cast the return from `malloc()`, `ptr=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*2)` should be `ptr=malloc(sizeof(int)*2)`, or even better, `ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr) * 2)`;

Comment: ... or even `ptr = malloc(2 * sizeof *ptr);`, in my world. :)

Comment: @unwind Yes, in this case I'm in the "prefer to add the parentheses" camp, even though they are unnecessary as you say.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths : `ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr) * 2);` is undefined as  OP has not stored any integer to the address pointer by the pointer.
So it may be any garbage value.

Comment: @kevingomes: It's not undefined behavior, here. `sizeof` doesn't evaluate its expression.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths : why?

Comment: @kevingomes: One, because it doesn't need to, it only needs to know the *type* of `*ptr`, not the value to which it points. Secondly, because `sizeof` works at compile time, so it can't.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths : `Secondly, because sizeof works at compile time, so it can't.`. I didn't get it?

Comment: @kevingomes: Meaning that at the time `sizeof` works, your program hasn't started running yet, so your `malloc()` call hasn't happened. It wouldn't be possible for it to deference the pointer and access that memory, because the memory hasn't been allocated yet.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths : As a conclusion can we say that `sizeof(ptr)` is same as `sizeof(*ptr)`

Comment: @kevingomes: No, we absolutely cannot say that. If `ptr` was type `char *`, for instance, then `sizeof(*ptr)` would evaluate to `1`, the same as `sizeof(char)`, and `sizeof(ptr)` would evaluate to whatever size `char` pointers are on the system in question, usually 4 or 8 these days. They're completely different.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths : oops sorry!!! I got it wrong. I was confused just because size of `int` and `*ptr` is same i.e. `4`

Comment: @kevingomes: On your system, perhaps. The system I'm on right now, for instance, is a 64 bit system where `sizeof(int)` is 4, but `sizeof(int *)` is 8. If `ptr` is type `int *`, then `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(*ptr)` will always be the same, since they are of the same type.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
int *ptr;
ptr = malloc(2 * sizeof *ptr);
printf("ptr = %p.\n", (void *) ptr); // Examine pointer before increment.
ptr++;
printf("ptr = %p.\n", (void *) ptr); // Examine pointer after increment.
```

You will see that the value of `ptr` is incremented by the number of bytes in an `int`. The C language automatically does pointer arithmetic in units of the pointed-to element. So a single increment of an `int` pointer in C becomes, at the machine level, an increment of the number of bytes of an `int`.

---

### Notes

`%p` is the proper specifier to use when printing a pointer, not `%d`. Also, the pointer must be cast to `void *` or `const void *`.

`ptr = malloc(2 * sizeof *ptr);` is a cleaner way to allocate memory and assign a pointer than your original code, because:

- Using `sizeof *ptr` causes the code to automatically adapt if you ever change the type of `ptr`. Instead of having to change the type in two places (where `ptr` is declared and where `malloc` is called), one change suffices. This reduces opportunities for errors.
- `malloc` does not need to be cast to the destination type. It returns a `void *`, which C will automatically convert to the destination type of the assignment without complaint. (C++ is different.) It will still work if you cast it, but this can mask another problem: If you accidentally do not declare `malloc` (as by failing to include `<stdlib.h>`, and compile in an old version of C, `malloc` will be implicitly declared to return an `int`, and the cast will mask the error. Leaving the expression without a cast will cause a warning message to be produced when this happens.

Answer (score 2):

This line changes value of address in pointer to some nonsense (100 will not be any valid address):

```
ptr=100;
```

Then you increment the pointer to `100 + sizeof(int)` because the pointer has type of `int*` which automatically increments address by amount of bytes to get to the next integer that ptr points to.

At next line you dereference the invalid pointer so your code should crash, but the command is ok if your pointer had valid address:

```
printf("ptr=%d",*ptr);
```

To repair your code just don't change the pointer itself but change the data:

```
int *ptr;      
ptr=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*2);       
*ptr=123;    /*What will happen if I put an asterisk(*) indicating *ptr=100? */            
printf("ptr=%d",*ptr);
ptr++;
*ptr=234;     
printf("ptr+1=%d",*ptr);
// you can set or get your data also this way:
ptr[0] = 333;
ptr[1] = 444;
printf("ptr[0]=%d",ptr[0]);
printf("ptr[1]=%d",ptr[1]);
free(ptr);
```

Answer (score 2):

First thing you need to understand is a POINTER points to ADDRESS, when your assign 100 to ptr, it means your pointer ptr now points to memory location whose address is 100.

Secondly pointer arithmetic depends on type of pointer, in your case ptr is a pointer pointing to integer. SO when you increment ptr, it means it will jump to the memory location of next integer. So, ptr gets incremented by 2 (memory occupied by one int on your platform)

Answer (score 0):

To be simple

```
ptr=100;
```

By this you are trying to store a `int` as an address to a pointer, which Is nonsense.
In other words you are trying to make the pointer `ptr` to point the address `100`, which is not an address.

But by

```
*ptr=100;
```

You are trying to store value `100` to the address pointed by `ptr`, which is valid.

Also

```
ptr++;
```

Means that now `ptr` is pointing to `ptr+4` or (`ptr+2` for 16 bit compiler like `tc`) address.

Also for your particular code, you are just changing and incrementing the address pointed by `ptr`, but you are not storing any value at the address pointed by `ptr`.
So your code will print garbage value or it may also crash as `100` is not a valid address.

Also you should have done

```
ptr=(int*)100;
```

It would remove

```
warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

But still it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Converting an integer to a pointer is implementation-defined behavior, not undefined. It could be meaningful on a variety of systems.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths : by undefined I meant that any value could be stored at the address pointed by `ptr`but the behaviour is defined.

Comment: Not necessarily - if you were working on a system that stored something meaningful at memory location `100`, the result would be well-defined by the implementation.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths : but user would be unaware of that value.

Comment: Not if he dereferenced the pointer, he wouldn't be. On the old microcomputers, for instance, it was pretty common to have hardcoded memory addresses for entry point locations to operating system API calls, for instance, or to other system provided values. The addresses would be listed in the computer's manual, and it was normal to access those memory locations explicitly, by manually using the address. The same thing could work these days on embedded systems, for instance.